# How to Create a Storybook App for Multiple Platform

Tags: android, ios

Basically I am trying to create a storybook app that is easily migrated between platforms (Android, iPhone, tablets) and has these features:
- "Read to Me" — listen to the narrated story with words highlighted as they are read
- "Read it Myself" — read the book in its traditional form.
- "Auto Play" — plays like a movie, automatically reading and turning pages.

For example the storybook app by Oceanhouse Media's "All By Myself - Little Critter" storybook app.

Looking around, these are the options I found:

1. Hybrid: jQuery Mobile + (PhoneGap or maybe just use WebView)
2. Native with OpenGL - Maybe too hard for me since I need to learn OpenGL + Maths! And not good with migrating between platforms
3. ThirdParty SDK : Corona, Titanium or Unity

Comment: Look at service orientated architecture to deliver the content and to allow users to login from multiple devices...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a question that has not yet, and actually will probably never, get a satisfactory answer.

Cross-platform has always been a problem from the dawn of computers and will continue to be one.

The only way to be cross-platform is to strip your app to a bear minimum feature-wise because every single new feature you are going to add will make it harder(a lot) or impossible to work on another platform.

Examples Webview : 
- Javascript performance on Android devices is horrendously slow so don't expect nice animation from it. 
- Communication from html pages to native Android is buggy to the last degree.

Example OpenGl : 
- iphone, android, blackberries do not use the same subset of opengl. I guess for a book reader this is not really a problem because they all have the same basic coverage. But you'll have to know and code the opengl launching for every single platform and work around bugs that are also platform dependent.

Example thirdparty sdks : You have to know that every time you add a third party sdk between you and the native platform you are actually adding the sdks' bugs to the native bugs. What usually looks good when you begin, end up being a mess when you are done trying to circumvent all these new bugs.

Now to answer your question : If you really want to go the cross platform route, you need to keep in mind that you will loose some functionalities along the way. Once you know about it, it's easier to let go :)

I went with the Html + webview and its doing ok for my purposes but is far from perfect.
If I had to do it again I would probably try a third party sdk like AIR from adobe which would be the best supported one(it's where the money is) but I hear some friends developers fighting with it quite a lot to achieve what they want. The results seem quite nice though : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBBNHEKIJkM

A final word : Be careful with the read out loud feature, it might be illegal : http://marilynnbyerly.com/texttospeechande.html

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks man!!  That is some real analysis there.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare your project to a game project :

- read to me : music background + user interactions + scripted event based display
- read it myself : user interactions + scripted event based display
- auto play : scripted event based display

In that case, your technical choice becomes easier to evaluate:

- Hybrid dev will be difficult to achieve because the level of interaction and control needed on the events will be high (for example pausing the narration, page flipping, etc.)
- Native opengl : better control but cross environnements and technical knowledges required make this choice very hazardous and complex to achieve
- Thirdparty sdk : may be the best choice, it will allow you to focus on the user features instead of the technical aspects. Unity does that very well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I will take a quick look on Unity. I wasn't really impressed with Corona's Android support.